# Search for files in given folder modified by specific user using Git

Tags: git

Consider a folder structure below:

```
- core
- src
  - models
    - User.js
    - Item.js
  - controllers
  - utilities
- web
```

If one wants a list of all files in `models` folder that have at least one line modified by user `Jack`, how can it be done using Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: --author=Jack -- 'src/models' | sort | uniq
```

`--name-only` shows the filenames that have been modified

`--pretty=format:` shows nothing else but the filenames

`--author=Jack` filters by author of the commit

`-- src/models` lets you specify the file pattern you want to match. You could use `'*.js'` to match all javascript files.

`sort | uniq` is to get rid of duplications.